# UITableViewCell's DetailTextLabel is null, missing something?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

I'm missing something I suspect is obvious but I can't find it.

```
UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell("MyCell");    
if (cell == null) {
        cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, "MyCell");
}

cell.TextLabel.Text = "Foo";
cell.DetailTextLabel.Text = "Foo2";
```

I'm getting a null reference exception with the `DetailTextLabel`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It's because you are using UITableViewCellStyle.Default. You need UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle if you want the detailsLabel.